Selenium only captures full urls for script src
im trying to capture all "src" elements in all  elements and it never gives me back urls like "/cdn/script.js" and only full urls like "site.com/cdn/script.js", how can i enable this?
def GetScriptArray():
  ScriptElements = Driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'script')
  for x, Script in enumerate(ScriptElements, start=1):
    ScriptSource = Script.get_attribute("src")
    ScriptSourceAlt = Script.get_attribute("data-original-src")
    if ScriptSource:
      if ScriptSource.startswith("http"):
        ScriptArray.append(ScriptSource)
      elif ScriptSource.startswith("//"):
        print("SPECIAL 1 : " + ScriptSource)
      elif ScriptSource.startswith("/"):
        print("SPECIAL 2 : " + ScriptSource)
    else:
      print("SCRIPT NUM " + str(x) + " HAS NO SRC")

The above script outputs the below (I'm testing on hugedomains.com/domain_profile.cfm?d=myecommercewebsite.com):
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60068/devtools/browser/a7437c3c-2acf-484f-9ec8-92c7fb9acca4
SCRIPT NUM 4 HAS NO SRC
SCRIPT NUM 5 HAS NO SRC
SCRIPT NUM 6 HAS NO SRC
SCRIPT NUM 7 HAS NO SRC
SCRIPT NUM 8 HAS NO SRC
SCRIPT NUM 9 HAS NO SRC
SCRIPT NUM 16 HAS NO SRC
SCRIPT NUM 17 HAS NO SRC
SCRIPT NUM 18 HAS NO SRC

[array with no cut urls (cant share because u cant post https://]
doesnt come up with no urls like "/cdn/script,js" only full urls...........

Where in your output are the 'full urls'? And what do you mean "u cant post https://"? Have you tried simply converting the full URLs to relative URLs using standard library functions?

by [array with cut urls] i mean a array with ONLY full urls, theres no urls like "/cdn-cgi/etc.js" (or its not recursively scanning scripts in other elements), also you cant post https:\site.com in questions for some reason

src attributes are interpreted by your browser as relative to the current url and/or host name, unless they start with https:.

My assumption is that you aren't letting the page fully load. I changed the approach, changed the <script> locator to script[src] to only pull tags that have an src attribute, added a wait, and it's working fine for me.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#url = f'file:///C:/Users/jbcro/Desktop/sample.html'
url = 'https://www.hugedomains.com/domain_profile.cfm?d=myecommercewebsite.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "header")))
tags = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "script[src]")
print("DEFAULT")
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get_attribute("src"))
print("")

iframes = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe")
for iframe in iframes:
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    tags = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "script[src]")
    print("IFRAME")
    for tag in tags:
        print(tag.get_attribute("src"))
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    print("")

It prints
DEFAULT
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/pPK749sccDmVW_9DSeTMVvh2/recaptcha__en.js
https://cdn-cookieyes.com/client_data/e71bc53f1cb88666d160c1e2/script.js
https://cdn-cookieyes.com/client_data/e71bc53f1cb88666d160c1e2/banner.js
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=6LdRB9UiAAAAABaf3jRLyU_gwaGIp-3OvR51myRx
https://static.hugedomains.com/js/hdv3-js/jquery.min.js
https://static.hugedomains.com/js/hdv3-js/script.js?aa=2022-10-32
https://static.hugedomains.com/js/hdv3-js/common.js
https://static.hugedomains.com/js/hdv3-js/hd-js.js?a=20220124b  
https://www.hugedomains.com/rjs/hdv3-rjs/hd-js.cfm?aa=2022-10-32

IFRAME
https://www.hugedomains.com/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/jsd/main.js

IFRAME
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/pPK749sccDmVW_9DSeTMVvh2/recaptcha__en.js
https://www.google.com/js/bg/1WJ41Y3FKQ963wNVVah2aO2i1At8ivplN5CN6DwMHdo.js

IFRAME


if you go to the exact page and put in ".js" into the search bar under inspect element the last query should be number 13 and it isn't a full url it's "/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/jsd/main.js"

I didn't realize you wanted the SCRIPT tags inside the IFRAMEs. I've updated my code.

thank you soo much, im looking into my code now to see how i can implement that use of selenium into my script
